# How to get maximum value from column while using joining sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I wrote following sql query

```
SELECT  ST.Roll, CR.Code, CR.Title, CR.Credits, SCH.ObtainedGPA
FROM [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[StudentCourseHistory]  AS SCH
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Student] AS ST ON SCH.StudentID = ST.StudentID
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Course] AS CR ON SCH.CourseID = CR.CourseID AND SCH.VersionID = CR.VersionID

WHERE ST.Roll ='0914BPM00387'
```

It return result like following

```
Roll            Code    Title                          Credits  ObtainedGPA  

0914BPM00387    BPM216  Physiology Lab -                   1    4.00         
0914BPM00387    BPM217  Pharmaceutical Microbiology        3    2.25         
0914BPM00387    BPM217  Pharmaceutical Microbiology        3    2.00          
0914BPM00387    BPM218  Pharmaceutical Microbiology Lab    1    3.50
```

Here BPM217 and BPM217 are same but it's ObtainedGrade is different 2.25 and 2.00. Now how can I get only the maximum value 2.25 from those two rows.

I need the sql query. Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  ST.Roll, CR.Code, CR.Title, CR.Credits, MAX(SCH.ObtainedGPA)
FROM [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[StudentCourseHistory]  AS SCH
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Student] AS ST ON SCH.StudentID = ST.StudentID
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Course] AS CR ON SCH.CourseID = CR.CourseID AND SCH.VersionID = CR.VersionID
WHERE ST.Roll ='0914BPM00387'
GROUP BY ST.Roll, CR.Code, CR.Title, CR.Credits
```